# How to move existing project to a group

Tags: gitlab

I have three existing projects that I want to put in one group in GitLab.

I did the following steps:

- Create a new group **supi**
- Go to project A => Settings => Advanced => Transfer project => Select namespace =>  **Group supi**
  (Now Project A's url moved from `git@gitlab.com:myname/project-a` to `git@gitlab.com:mygroup/project-a`)
- I changed the url inside of my local copy from project A `git remote set-url origin git@gitlan.com:mygroup/project-a`

I thought that everything will work from here, however, when I call `git pull` from my local project A I get this:

> Your configuration specifies to merge with the ref 'refs/heads/master'
>   from the remote, but no such ref was fetched.

What does it mean?

This is the content of my .git/config file:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@gitlab.com:mygroup/project-a.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue, I had no files in the repository. Adding a `readme.md` made it work.